# How to parse read json elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to create cart system in my mobile application, i want to store the id and the quantity of products, the id should be the key of my array (for modifying product quantity) , tried to use object instead of array but i get error: undefined is not a function when i try to read my json variable

by  JSON.stringify(cart)

My cart code is like this

```
var cart = [];
var produit = {}; 
produit['qte'] = $('.'+id_prd).text();
produit['id_produit'] = id_prd;
cart[id_prd] = produit;
window.sessionStorage["cart1"]= JSON.stringify(cart);
```

return me

```
{"7":{"qte":"1","id_produit":7},"8":{"qte":"1","id_produit":8}}
```

when I tried to parse the json string with

```
 var parsed = $.parseJSON(window.sessionStorage["cart1"]);
```

i get the error 'undefined is not a function'
when triying to read the json with

```
 var i=0;
  for (k in parsed) {
    var k_data = parsed[k];
    k_data.forEach(function(entry) {                              



    alert(entry);

    ch+=entry.id_produit;
    if(i<parsed.length-1)
     ch+= ',';
    if(i==parsed.length-1)
        ch+=')';
    i++;
 });
 }
```

Can you clarify me the error cause, and if there's a solution to better read the json

Comment: `JSON.parse(jsonString)`

Comment: remove the double quote in front of id_produit

Comment: it is a typo i will edit my question

Comment: is "parse" and "parse1" the same variable?

Comment: @chepe263 yes this is also a typo, i'm really confused

Comment: Is the JSON always like that one, or it can have more JSONS integrated in it? It it is always the same, look to my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `k_data.forEach(function(entry)` but forEach is for Arrays, and k_data is just a simple javascript object.

Try changing:

`k_data.forEach(function(entry){`

to this:

`$(k_data).each(function(entry){`

Even more, if the JSON is always in the same structure you posted, I think the each function is not necessary, maybe this is the way you are looking for:

```
var i=0;
var ch = "(";
for (k in parsed) {
    var k_data = parsed[k];                         

    alert(k_data);

    ch+=k_data.id_produit;
    ch+= ',';
    i++;
}
ch = ch.substring(0, ch.length - 1) + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var finalArr = new Array();
     var dataArr = new Array();
     dataArr  = window.sessionStorage["cart1"];
     if (JSON.parse(dataArr).length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < JSON.parse(dataArr).length; i++) {
                finalArr.push((JSON.parse(dataArr))[i]);
            }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: I get this 
Object {7: Object, 8: Object}
7: Object
8: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: can any1 tel why did u vote down my answer ? how is it not useful ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need jQuery for this. The same JSON object you used to stringify has a parse function:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage["cart1"]);
```

If that still breaks, there's probably something wrong with another undefined object.